# What's the difference between event handling and functions generated by double-click on form in designer in C#?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, event-handling

What is the difference between C# event handling (with all the delegates and things like that) and the events generated by double clicking on a form in designer (in Visual Studio) ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There's no difference.
The event handling and delegate are automatically declared by Visual Studio, and the code is written in the .Designer.cs

Comment: So this is quite an overkill to manually write all this event handlers (delegates, classes with arguments, classes with event handlers, etc.) over automatically generated ones by VS ?

Comment: well if you have no particular reason to change the default behavior, yes, it is just a waste of time.

Comment: Can you give an example for behavior I might want that would require using manually written events ?

Comment: @lordmonkey: a simple example would be a situation where you have one method that you want every button on a form to call. You *could* double-click every button in the designer and call the method from every delegate created thusly, but an easier way would be to write a function that iterates through all the buttons on the form and manually assigns a single handler to every button.

Comment: Another example i could give you is from an application I wrote recently. I had to manually create the menu item on a form based on the data in a specific table of a database. Obviously to handle the Click event i couldn't double click in the designer simply because the item were not present at design time